# What are the use cases of identifying process id of a log message?

Tags: node.js

I'm researching node.js logging tools. The top 2 ones seem to be Winston and Bunyan. In the comparison article, it's mentioned how to get the process id.

What is the use case of knowing this process ID? When is it useful?

I mainly develop web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have one log file that the application writes to. A few use cases could be:

- if you have multiple processes logging to the same file (child processes) you can tell them apart
- if a process crashes or is restarted, the pid will change, which indicates that this has happened
- if you are debugging something it might be useful to see a change of events, so you need the pid to group them together